# Wait for eventmachine queue to be empty?

Tags: ruby, resque, eventmachine

I'm using a Ruby library that assumes its running inside eventmachine (Faye) and starts the eventmachine reactor in a separate thread if it isn't inside an EM.run context. When the Rails application is started inside a thin server, no problem.  But for background jobs the Rails environment is loaded and then resque is started, which spawns a new process for every job (the self.perform method below).

So, I know that I have the reactor running, but I need to know when it is safe to return from `self.perform` because that will exit the current process and cut off any pending actions in the EM reactor. Alternatively I could run the job inside an `EM.run` block but would then need to know when it is safe to exit.

```
class AsanaPopulateJob
  @queue = :profiles

  def self.logger; Rails.logger; end

  def self.perform(ident_id)
    begin
      logger.debug "==> Start AsanaPopulateJob[#{ident_id}]"
      ident = Identity.find(ident_id)
      conn = AsanaConnector.new(ident)
      Faye.ensure_reactor_running!
      conn.populate_profile!
      logger.debug "=== Sleep 5..."
      sleep(5)
    ensure
      logger.debug "<== Done AsanaPopulateJob[#{ident_id}]"
    end
  end
end
```

Right now, I'm running my function call that invokes em-hiredis and then sleeping for 5 seconds to let things settle down.  Surely there's something better.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Please give a short code example and add some more context to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: As I know, every method you want to exe in `EM.run`, you can return a result status, then let EM defer current job.